# How can I re-create a docker mysql image that uses a volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using docker-compose to create a mysql container, and create a database in it. If I delete the database manually, no matter what I do, I can't re-create the container and force it to re-create the database too.

Here's my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysqltest-db
    image: mysql:5.6.51
    volumes:
      - ./my_volume:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./data/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.init.sql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
       MYSQL_DATABASE: my_database
       MYSQL_USER: my_user
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypass

volumes:
  my_volume: {}
```

The init.sql script simply creates a database:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_database;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_database.* TO my_user@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The **first time** I run `docker-compose up`, everything works fine. I can log into the mysql with `docker container exec -it mysqltest-db bash`, then log into mysql with `mysql -u root -proot`, and run `show databases`. Sure enough, `my_database` is there:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| my_database        |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Next I **manually delete** the database by running `drop database my_database`.

Then I ctrl+c to kill the container, and run `docker-compose down -v`. As I understand it, the `-v` should destroy the volume that contained the mysql data. I check that it's really gone by running `docker volume ls`, and confirm that the `dockertest_my_volume` volume is no longer present.

Then I run `docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -V --force-recreate` to re-create the container. This is where I'm stuck. When I login to the container, and then to mysql, and run `show databases` again, the my_database is still gone:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**What am I missing to force Docker to completely rebuild from scratch, so that the mysql database gets created the second time?**

There is clearly a big difference in the amount of log output between the first and second runs. However in both cases, it *seems* to create a volume:

```
$-> docker-compose up -V --force-recreate
Docker Compose is now in the Docker CLI, try `docker compose up`

Creating network "dockertest_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "dockertest_my_volume" with default driver
Creating mysqltest-db ... done
Attaching to mysqltest-db
```

Answer (score 2):

Wow, an easy one at last. Docker volumes are names, not paths. You have:

```
volumes:
      - ./my_volume:/var/lib/mysql
```

Which mounts a path on your local filesystem relative to the context (the folder where you started the container), `./my_volume`, into the container at path `/var/lib/mysql`. What you really want is this:

```
volumes:
      - my_volume:/var/lib/mysql
```

Which contains a volume reference (a named volume). This creates/mounts the volume `my_volume` into `/var/lib/mysql` within the container.

You can diagnose the problem because you'll have a directory called `my_volume` next to the `docker-compose.yaml` file. Another way to check this is to execute `docker volume ls` while the container is running and you'll notice that there is no `my_volume` volume (when running your code, not mine -- when you run mine it'll work ;).

Easily fixed though :)

Answer (score 2):

Docker has two kinds of built-in storage, [named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) and [bind mounts](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).  The syntax of these is very similar, but a named volume attaches Docker-managed storage to a container, and a bind mount directly attaches some host directory instead.

Your `docker-compose.yml` file says:

```yaml
volumes:
  - ./my_volume:/var/lib/mysql
```

This is the bind-mount syntax; it names a path directly on your host system.  (If you look you can see the `my_volume` directory and the MySQL data files within it.)

The MySQL image startup sequence knows to look in the `/var/lib/mysql` directory, and *if that directory is empty* it does the first-time initialization sequence.  If there's a MySQL installation there, it will not re-run the initialization scripts, even if you've deleted the content there.  This is the same behavior if it's a named volume or a bind mount.

In your case, even though you've deleted the database, the MySQL system files are still there.  You can force it to start from scratch:

```sh
docker-compose rm --stop mysql
rm -rf my_volume
docker-compose up -d
```